# be killed in the war vs be killed by the war

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, difference

Please tell me the difference in nuance between the following two setences.

1. A lot of people were killed in the war.
2. A lot of people were killed by the war.

Comment: Killed in (or during) the war is more usual. However: A lot of people were traumatised **by** the war.

Comment: Strictly speaking, "killed by the war" means that it was the war that killed them. "Killed in the war" means that they were killed during the war (by someone or something). In practice, there is no difference in nuance. Usage of prepositions is largely a matter of convention (established usage). There is often no "why?"

Comment: If someone died of grief, then you could say that they were killed by the war (since it wasn't a soldier or bomb that killed them).

Comment: I realized the difference in nuance between them. Thank you for your kind comments.

Comment: So there **is** a difference in nuance. It just took me some time to find it. :-]

Comment: If both were talking about someone actually getting killed, I would say "by" sounds more like a civilian killed due to the war, and "in" would be a soldier serving being killed... that's just what it sounds like, to me (US Native), though. I'm not sure about the actual grammar rules

Comment: @Jojodmo It's entirely usage, not grammar, and as a fellow USian that's exactly the distinction that came to my mind.

Answer (score 7):

For whatever reason people aren't usually killed *by* war.  They are killed (or wounded) *in* a war, often *by* enemy action.

I don't know why. Possibly because war is the result of human action, and some human is ultimately responsible.  This as compared with accident or disease, for example:

> He was killed by typhoid while in a prisoner-of-war camp.
>
> They were killed by flooding after the enemy bombed the dam.

Even though "the war" was *indirectly* responsible, for whatever reason we don't see war as the [proximate cause](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/proximate-cause).

As Mick points out, in some special cases you can say "he was killed by the war" to distinguish his death from happening *in* the war (as a result of battle).  But it's kind of a *metaphorical* use of the phrase, that implies war was *directly* responsible, when he was actually directly killed by something like grief or depression or malnutrition.

[Edit] This holds true whether you are killed "by war" or "by the war".  The only difference is whether you are talking generally about "war" or about a specific, *known* war. It's still an unusual expression, but again, certainly possible in the right context.

> "How did she die?"
>   "She was killed by the war."
>   "You mean, she died in a battle?"
>   "No, you see her husband was killed early on, and she just couldn't continue living without him. So, in a way, the war killed her."

Comment: I'm not sure of the reason for this, either, but it seems to be prepositional nomenclature that caught on around the time of World War I. [Interesting ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=killed+in+the+war%2Ckilled+by+the+war&year_start=1880&year_end=1980).

Comment: Mr. Andrew, I'm glad to know you taught a lot of students in Japan. Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: @KenichiroYokozawa ど いたしまして.

Comment: `...people aren't usually killed by war...` True, but they can be killed by ***the*** war.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  No, that's what I mean.  "War" isn't considered a cause of death.  An "act of war" is a cause of death, so you can say "he was killed by an act of war" but not usually "he was killed by war", except perhaps in a metaphorical context.  In literature, "War" itself is frequently anthropomorphized, in which case you can have "war" do anything.

Comment: The OP has the definite article in his second sentence, it's only fair to point out that the second sentence is *possible*, grammatically and metaphorically speaking. I also agree with everything you said in your comment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh, I see what you mean.  In that case the only difference is whether you are referring to generic "war" or a specific *known* war.  It's still an unusual expression, but certainly possible in the right context.

Comment: Done, plus added some context.  :)

Answer (score 4):

There is really nothing wrong with using **by** here. It's really just a matter of emphasis.

We customarily say

> He was killed **in** the war.

which is shorthand for distancing the event and placing it in time, but the emphasis shifts suddenly when you say

> He was killed **by** the war.

which suggests agency: the war is the cause of his death, and while it may not be the "proximate" cause it is undoubtedly the *root* cause. If there hadn't been a war there wouldn't have been a battle, say, where he took a bullet in the head. This is entirely a literal statement.

To turn that into a metaphor the war would have to be at a conceptual remove. Let's say someone drank himself to death after witnessing and participating in the horrors of war. Then it would be a bona fide metaphorical usage to say:

> **A**: It was his alcoholism that killed him, wasn't it?
>   **B**: Actually, he was killed by the war. He never drank before he went off to fight.

Answer (score 4):

> A lot of people were killed in the war.

A lot of people participated in the war and those people who participated were killed.  This would typically included combatants and those in contact with the combatants.

> A lot of people were killed by the war.

This would more refer to people who weren't participating in the war, but maybe indirectly affected by it.  For example, if a  battle blocked access to hospitals, and civilians died as a result of not being able to get there, those civilians could be said to be killed by the war.

*In the war* can also refer to *within the timeframe the war was happening* so it's not incorrect to say civiliians were killed *in* the war as well.

One may want to say a soldier was killed *by* the war in order to give the impression the soldier didn't necessarily want to be in the war, but had to go anyway, e.g. conscription.

Answer (score 1):

To slightly mangle an NRA slogan, "wars don't kill people; people kill people."

A war may be reasonably defined as an event where two (or more) groups of people threaten (and often, with more or less success, try) to kill each other, unless the other group of people does what they want (which, on one side, *may* simply be "stop trying to kill us, damnit!").  As such, people often do get killed in wars.

However, saying that someone was killed *by* the war is getting the cause and the effect backwards.  The fact that there was a war did not cause people to die (unless they got so depressed by the war that they drank themselves to death, as in [Robusto's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/113293), or something like that); rather, the fact that people were killed is what made the situation into a war, as opposed to just a diplomatic conflict.

In a way, saying "he was killed by the war" is wrong for much the same reason as saying "the snow fell *by* a blizzard" would be — it's not the blizzard that makes the snow fall, it's the snow falling that makes it a blizzard.